# How to pass parameters in PowerShell script which executes in WinSCP command?

Tags: powershell, winscp

I have a PowerShell script

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
. .\WinSCP.exe /console /script="L:\Work\SAS Data\FTP\local2remote.txt"  /log=log.txt
```

It calls WinSCP command file

```
option batch on
open ftp://user:pass@host -passive=on
lcd "J:\Work\SAS Data\Roman\Lists"
put target.csv
exit
```

I want to convert "J:\Work\SAS Data\Roman\Lists" to a parameter in the PowerShell script where the parameter can be passed in the txt file. Same goes for the file target.csv. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You better use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) from your [PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (and one that doesn't involve writing a temporary script file) would be to switch to [`/command`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#example) for WinSCP:

```
# You don't need the . operator to run external programs
.\WinSCP.exe /console /log=log.txt /command `
  'open ftp://user:pass@host -passive=on' `
  'lcd "J:\Work\SAS Data\Roman\Lists"' `
  'put target.csv' `
  'exit'
```

Now you have a much easier time incorporating script parameters:

```
param([string] $Path, [string] $FileName)

& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe' /console /log=log.txt /command `
  'open ftp://user:pass@host -passive=on' `
  "lcd `"$Path`"" `
  "put `"$FileName`"" `
  'exit'
```

However, you *can* of course, still write a command file and pass that:

```
$script = Join-Path $Env:TEMP winscp-commands.txt

"open ftp://user:pass@host -passive=on
lcd ""$Path""
put ""$FileName""
exit" | Out-File -Encoding Default $script

& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe' /console /log=log.txt /script=$script
Remove-Item $script
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift method. However, I get an error as follows for the second script.  Error changing directory to $Path

Comment: `$Path` shouldn't even appear in the commands WinSCP gets. Did you use single quotes instead of double quotes by any chance?

Comment: Yup that's it. Thanks @Joey !

Comment: Hey @Joey, it prompts an error 'too many parameters for command lcd'. Do you know any solution around this?

Comment: @KaranPappala: Are you sure _your_ original code worked? Since you already were using `lcd` with a path that contains spaces, I was assuming things to work. It appears that you have to quote such names, then. I'll edit, accordingly.

Comment: you are correct. Double quotes was used in the original code. I have added that to the question. And the original code worked.

Comment: Hi @Joey, the script "lcd `"$Path`"" ` runs tillteh space only. It did not resolve the blank space issue.

Comment: Even 'lcd "J:\Work\SAS Data\Roman\Lists"' ` in the first script gives the same issue. It works when it is put in the text file.

Comment: Here, https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1708 , it says from command line spaces cannot be dealt due to windows parsing capabilities

Comment: @Karan: That's not a limitation of Windows parsing, as each application is itself responsible for its command-line parsing. But it's a convenient excuse if the author is incapable of writing a parser. I amended the answer to use a script again.